# How to convert char[] to Character[]?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, char, character

I'm new to Java and trying to figure out how to convert `char[]` to `Character[]`. Since `ArrayList.add()` method only allows `Character[]`, while my charAry is a `char[]`. Appreciate your time and patience!

```java
List<Character[]> lCharAry = new ArrayList<>();
char[] charAry = new char[50];

for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < charAry.length; i++) {
        charAry = list.get(j).toCharArray();
    }
    lCharAry.add(charAry);
}
```

Comment: what is list object here ?

Comment: You could, strictly from a Java perspective, make `lCharAry` a  `List<char[]>`, which would allow you to add `char[]` items directly to it.  Would that be an option for you, or is it a requirement that  `lCharAry` be a `List<Character[]>`?

Comment: otherwise u will have to iterate over char[] array and convert it using Character.valueOf('C')

Comment: Thank you all! @Kevin Anderson Yes!!! it worked! I thought I could only use List<Character[]>, apparently I was wrong... Thanks again!